# Reload a csv file and call the same view with it

Tags: python, csv, d3.js, flask

I have two templates (`initial.html` and `index.html`) containing (among others thing) a form. I use data from this form to generate a csv (`data.csv`) and then read it in the `index.html` thanks to `d3` and `parcoords.js`. Each new submission generate a new `data.csv`

The thing is, on the first call, everything seems to work but the moment I try to submit the form with new values the visualization does not change (even if the file `data.csv` appears to change when I open it with TextEdit)

Moreover, the data (`values` in `main.py` )  I provide to the view does not change either.
I know it is not recommended to call the same view after a POST submission but even if I try to call a different view, both of the problems described below remains.

Relevant parts of code are as follows:

`main.py`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def main():

    global maxDepth
    global numberOfRelated

    if request.method=='POST':
        url = request.form['url']
        maxDepth = int(request.form['depth'])
        numberOfRelated = int(request.form['numberOfRelated'])
        values = crawling(url,maxDepth,numberOfRelated)
        return render_template('index.html',var=values)
    return render_template('initial.html')
```

the `crawling` function

```
def crawling(url,maxDepth,numberOfRelated):

    start = time.time()

    initialID = get_id(url)

    videosId.append([0,initialID])
    getAllID(1,initialID)

    getVideoData(videosId)
    if os.path.exists('static/csv/data.csv'):
       os.remove('static/csv/data.csv')

    with open('static/csv/data.csv','wb') as csvData:
        dataWriter = csv.writer(csvData, delimiter='|', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        dataWriter.writerow(['Depth']+['ID']+['Title']+['Popularity']+['Occurency'])
        for x in xrange(0,len(videosData)):
            dataWriter.writerow([videosData[x].level]+[videosData[x].id]+[videosData[x].title.encode("utf-8")]+[videosData[x].popularite]+[videosData[x].occurence])

    timeExecution = round(time.time() - start,1)
    mostFrequent = mostFrequentVideo()
    mostPopular = mostPopularVideo()
    initialVideo = videosData[0]

    return  [initialVideo,mostPopular, mostFrequent, len(videosData), timeExecution]
```

The form

```
  <nav class="navbar formSpace">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-inline" action="" method="POST">

        <div class="service form-group">
          <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i>          
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mainForm"  placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HIuN5lxMCI" name="url" />
          </div>             
           <div class="form-group minorForm">
            <input  name='numberOfRelated' type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Number of suggestion" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group minorForm">
            <input  name='depth' type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="depth" />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group navbar-right">
            <button class="btn btn-success minorForm generate" type="submit"> Generate</button>
          </div> 
       </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

`main.js`

```
 var pc0;

var blue_to_brown = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 5])
  .range(["red", "#3498db"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab);


d3.csv('static/csv/data.csv?_='+ Math.random(), function(data) {
pc0 = d3.parcoords()("#example0")
  .data(data)
    .showControlPoints(false)
    .hideAxis(["Title"])
    .hideAxis(["ID"])
    .composite("darker")
    .width(860)
    .color(function(d) { return blue_to_brown(d['Depth']);})
    .render()
    .alpha(0.35)
    .brushMode("1D-axes")
    .reorderable()
    .interactive();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask serves static files that tell the browser to *cache* the file rather aggressively. The default is to tell the browser to cache the file for 12 hours.

You can bypass this cache by adding a random value to the URL;

```
d3.csv('static/csv/data.csv?_=' + Math.random(), function(data) {
```

Now the browser will see this as a new URL each time and not re-use the cached file.

Comment: I also thought it was a cache problem, I used your trick but the d3 visualization is not visible anymore as if it doesn't find the path to the CSV. (Considering I'm not a JavaScript expert, I've tried Math.random().toString() guessing it was a type problem but it does not work either)

Comment: It is just a URL. Check your browser console and Flask log to see what might be wrong here; adding a query parameter (with a `?`) should just work.

Comment: I had `var test = 'static/csv/data.csv?_=' + Math.random();`  to `main.js` and my browser console return indeed a valid URL that leads to the file, but despite that, the visualization remains invisible.

Comment: And your browser console shows nothing? Are there requests being made?

Comment: The console shows `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`  from `d3.parcoords.js`  (meaning that the js file failed to load the data I guess, even if your trick seems to works). I thought the problem comes from the way I create and/or modified the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the solution

The trick advised by Martijn Pieters works perfectly fine, the problem was coming from the format of my CSV. (I was using '|' instead of ',' and D3 didn't like that)